# <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" tools:node="remove"/> will cause a problem?

Tags: android, sdk, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When I have removed com.android.vending.BILLING from my manifest it is showing this error while purchasing.

But in debug mode, it is not showing.
Only in the play store apk, I am able to see

[SHOWING ERROR WHILE PURCHASING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Too8M.jpg)

Comment: as of google official announcement few years back above was not needed inside manifest anymore you can read more about that here .
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#release-1_0

Comment: i tested it by commenting the above in manifest it works in both Debug and Manifest for me please make sure you have the latest version of library in your gradle.

Comment: But when I update the apk in the play store with the latest version then download and tested I am getting this issue [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Too8M.jpg